# Google Maps Event Click at Firefox 39 with Elements position:realtive

Tags: css, api, firefox, maps, pins

In Firefox 39 (updated today) i need a DOUBLECLICK to fire a Click-Event on the Pins.

The Problem is the Layer #top and its position "relative".

Does anyone know a solution without changing the layout?

Firefox 38.x and any other Browser works.

http://www.willstdumitunsgehen.at/

Answer (score 0):

Its a GOOGLE-Maps Bug with Firefox 39.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175863